# In Combo Box c# how can i select another value per item

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Every time i click on the combo box it shows the list of EmpID

I want to show the EmployeeName on the combo box but it will get the EmpID

Here is my code

```
private void EmployeeTimecard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSPOSWare.Reports.Properties.Settings.chaplinConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) AS Employee, EmpID from Employee ", conn))
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(rdr["EmpID"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.GrpEmpCBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    chkAll.Checked = true;
}
```

[This is where i get the employee name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vOoj.jpg)

[This is where i want to get the empID from the Employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GceCB.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

use like the following :

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    ListItem comboItem = new ListItem();
    comboItem.Text = rdr["Employee"].ToString();
    comboItem.Value = rdr["EmpID"].ToString();
    GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(comboItem);
}
```

So that you can select the value from the dropdown using the code below:

```
string selectedText = GrpEmpCBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); // which gives you the Employee
string selectedValue = GrpEmpCBox.SelectedValue;// gives you EmpID
```

A smart option is Bind the combobox using a Datatable like this:

```
string query = "Select (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) AS Employee, EmpID from Employee ";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GrpEmpCBox.DisplayMember =  "Employee";
GrpEmpCBox.ValueMember = "EmpID ";
GrpEmpCBox.DataSource = dt;
GrpEmpCBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: private string GetEmp()
        {
            return GrpEmpCBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }


if i use the SelectedValue it display " An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' "

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the values into your combo box like;

```
GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(rdr["EmpID"].ToString());
```

`EmpID` should be changed to your `Employee` string you have created.

However, you may want to read both in, having the name as the display, and the ID as the value.

Comment: Yes i can do that but the record in the table where i want to get the data only has EmpID column 

that is my problem ..

Comment: Ok, then you will need to show us some table schema and sample data so we can see how to return the employee names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that empname is the required employee name

```
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(rdr["EmpName"].ToString());
            }
        }
```